# How to reverse key value pair in list with dictionary as value?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a key value pair as below:

```
((1,{'foo':1,'abc':2,'xyz':3,'def':2}),(2,{'ghu':3,'kie':2}))
```

I was able to reverse the key value pair to below form:

```
((({'foo':1,'abc':2,'xyz':3,'def':2}),1),(({'ghu':3,'kie':2})),2)
```

But I need the in them in the following format.Tried with various options but was not successful

```
(({'foo':1}),1)
(({'abc':2}),1)
(({'xyz':3}),1)
(({'def':2}),1)
(({'ghu':3}),2)
(({'kie':2}}),2)
```

Could any one help me with this?

Comment: Is the above part of a bigger tuple? I mean the output format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list comprehension will produce your desired format:

```
l = ((1,{'foo':1,'abc':2,'xyz':3,'def':2}),(2,{'ghu':3,'kie':2}))
tuple((({k:v}),i) for i,j in l for k,v in j.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

If tuple is what you want, then you can use a simple `generator expression` like the following and then pass it to `tuple()` function to get the required tuple.

Example -

```
>>> t = ((1,{'foo':1,'abc':2,'xyz':3,'def':2}),(2,{'ghu':3,'kie':2}))
>>>
>>> nt = tuple((({k:d[k]}),i) for i, d in t for k in d.keys())
>>> nt
(({'def': 2}, 1), ({'xyz': 3}, 1), ({'abc': 2}, 1), ({'foo': 1}, 1), ({'kie': 2}, 2), ({'ghu': 3}, 2))
```

Comment: Anand,Can I maintain the same order as in the list?I just wanted to reverse the key,values and maintain the same order as in the dictionary.

Comment: need to update input tuple to get same order. Need Order Dictionary in input tuple.

Comment: Dictionary has no order, there is no way you can get the keys in order from dictionary, if you want the initial dictionary to have order, use `collections.OrderedDict` (from Python 2.7 onwards) . If you are using OrderedDict, then the above would maintain order.

Comment: Thanks guys,let me check with my code and get back.Will confirm the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate on every item from the given tuple.
2. Iterate second element for the item i.e. dictionary part.
3. create new item i.e. (({key:value},), item[0])
4. Append result into output variable.

**Code:**

```
input_val = ((1,{'foo':1,'abc':2,'xyz':3,'def':2}),(2,{'ghu':3,'kie':2}))

output_val = []
for i in input_val:
    for key, value in i[1].items():
        output_val.append( (({key:value},), i[0]))

import pprint
pprint.pprint(output_val)
```

Output:

```
[(({'xyz': 3},), 1),
 (({'foo': 1},), 1),
 (({'abc': 2},), 1),
 (({'def': 2},), 1),
 (({'ghu': 3},), 2),
 (({'kie': 2},), 2)]
```